# Asynchronous Code Inspections

Tags: c#, asynchronous, rubberduck

Rubberduck code inspections can take quite a while to complete, so I decided to run them on a background thread instead of locking up the IDE. The only drawback is... the IDE isn't locked-up while inspections are running, so the user can end up with inspection results that go against stale parse results - this could mean stale inspection results (say you add `Option Explicit` to a module that didn't have it), or stale token positioning (say you add or remove lines of code; every inspection result refering to a token located below that will be misplaced when navigating).

But the UX is worth it.. I think.

The status label indicates when parsing is happening...

[image: parsing...]

...and when inspections are running:

[image: inspecting...]

All results are populated at once in the grid:

[image: completed (4 issues)]

And there's a distinct status when no issues are found:

[image: completed (no issues)]

Here's the presenter code:

```
namespace Rubberduck.UI.CodeInspections
{
    public class CodeInspectionsDockablePresenter : DockablePresenterBase
    {
        private CodeInspectionsWindow Control { get { return UserControl as CodeInspectionsWindow; } }

        private IEnumerable<VBProjectParseResult> _parseResults;
        private IList<ICodeInspectionResult> _results;
        private readonly IInspector _inspector;

        public CodeInspectionsDockablePresenter(IInspector inspector, VBE vbe, AddIn addin, CodeInspectionsWindow window)
            :base(vbe, addin, window)
        {
            _inspector = inspector;
            _inspector.IssuesFound += OnIssuesFound;
            _inspector.Reset += OnReset;
            _inspector.Parsing += OnParsing;
            _inspector.ParseCompleted += OnParseCompleted;

            Control.RefreshCodeInspections += OnRefreshCodeInspections;
            Control.NavigateCodeIssue += OnNavigateCodeIssue;
            Control.QuickFix += OnQuickFix;
            Control.CopyResults += OnCopyResultsToClipboard;
        }

        // indicates that the _parseResults are no longer in sync with the UI
        private bool _needsResync;

        private void OnParseCompleted(object sender, ParseCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            ToggleParsingStatus(false);
            if (sender == this)
            {
                _needsResync = false;
                _parseResults = e.ParseResults;
                Task.Run(() => RefreshAsync());
            }
            else
            {
                _parseResults = e.ParseResults;
                _needsResync = true;
            }
        }

        private void OnParsing(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ToggleParsingStatus();
            Control.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate
            {
                Control.EnableRefresh(false);
            });
        }

        private void ToggleParsingStatus(bool isParsing = true)
        {
            Control.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate
            {
                Control.ToggleParsingStatus(isParsing);
            });
        }

        private void OnCopyResultsToClipboard(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var results = string.Join("\n", _results.Select(FormatResultForClipboard));
            var text = string.Format("Rubberduck Code Inspections - {0}\n{1} issue" + (_results.Count != 1 ? "s" : string.Empty) + " found.\n",
                            DateTime.Now, _results.Count) + results;

            Clipboard.SetText(text);
        }

        private string FormatResultForClipboard(ICodeInspectionResult result)
        {
            var module = result.QualifiedSelection.QualifiedName;
            return string.Format(
                "{0}: {1} - {2}.{3}, line {4}",
                result.Severity,
                result.Name,
                module.Project.Name,
                module.Component.Name,
                result.QualifiedSelection.Selection.StartLine);
        }

        private int _issues;
        private void OnIssuesFound(object sender, InspectorIssuesFoundEventArg e)
        {
            Interlocked.Add(ref _issues, e.Issues.Count);
            Control.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate
            {
                var newCount = _issues;
                Control.SetIssuesStatus(newCount);
            });
        }

        private void OnQuickFix(object sender, QuickFixEventArgs e)
        {
            e.QuickFix(VBE);
            _needsResync = true;
            OnRefreshCodeInspections(null, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        public override void Show()
        {
            base.Show();
            Task.Run(() => RefreshAsync());
        }

        private void OnNavigateCodeIssue(object sender, NavigateCodeEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                e.QualifiedName.Component.CodeModule.CodePane.SetSelection(e.Selection);
            }
            catch (COMException)
            {
                // gulp
            }
        }

        private void OnRefreshCodeInspections(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Task.Run(() => RefreshAsync()).ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                Control.SetIssuesStatus(_results.Count, true);
            });
        }

        private async Task RefreshAsync()
        {
            Control.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate
            {
                Control.EnableRefresh(false);
                Control.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            });

            try
            {
                if (VBE != null)
                {
                    if (_parseResults == null || _needsResync)
                    {
                        _inspector.Parse(VBE, this);
                        return;
                    }

                    var parseResults = _parseResults.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Project == VBE.ActiveVBProject);
                    if (parseResults == null || _needsResync)
                    {
                        _inspector.Parse(VBE, this);
                        return;
                    }

                    _results = await _inspector.FindIssuesAsync(parseResults);

                    Control.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate
                    {
                        Control.SetContent(_results.Select(item => new CodeInspectionResultGridViewItem(item))
                            .OrderBy(item => item.Component)
                            .ThenBy(item => item.Line));
                    });
                }
            }
            catch (COMException exception)
            {
                // swallow
            }
            finally
            {
                Control.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate
                {
                    Control.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
                    Control.SetIssuesStatus(_issues, true);
                    Control.EnableRefresh();
                });
            }
        }

        private void OnReset(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _issues = 0;
            Control.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate
            {
                Control.SetIssuesStatus(_issues);
                Control.InspectionResults.Clear();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the code-behind for the window:

```
namespace Rubberduck.UI.CodeInspections
{
    public partial class CodeInspectionsWindow : UserControl, IDockableUserControl
    {
        private const string ClassId = "D3B2A683-9856-4246-BDC8-6B0795DC875B";
        string IDockableUserControl.ClassId { get { return ClassId; } }
        string IDockableUserControl.Caption { get { return "Code Inspections"; } }

        public BindingList<CodeInspectionResultGridViewItem> InspectionResults 
        {
            get { return CodeIssuesGridView.DataSource as BindingList<CodeInspectionResultGridViewItem>; }
            set { CodeIssuesGridView.DataSource = value; }
        }

        public CodeInspectionsWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            RefreshButton.Click += RefreshButtonClicked;
            QuickFixButton.ButtonClick += QuickFixButton_Click;
            GoButton.Click += GoButton_Click;
            PreviousButton.Click += PreviousButton_Click;
            NextButton.Click += NextButton_Click;
            CopyButton.Click += CopyButton_Click;

            var items = new List<CodeInspectionResultGridViewItem>();
            CodeIssuesGridView.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
            CodeIssuesGridView.DataSource = new BindingList<CodeInspectionResultGridViewItem>(items);

            CodeIssuesGridView.AutoResizeColumns();
            CodeIssuesGridView.Columns["Issue"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;

            CodeIssuesGridView.SelectionChanged += CodeIssuesGridView_SelectionChanged;
            CodeIssuesGridView.CellDoubleClick += CodeIssuesGridView_CellDoubleClick;
        }

        public void ToggleParsingStatus(bool enabled = true)
        {
            StatusLabel.Image = enabled
                ? Resources.hourglass
                : Resources.exclamation_diamond;
            StatusLabel.Text = enabled
                ? RubberduckUI.Parsing
                : RubberduckUI.CodeInspections_Inspecting;
        }

        public void SetIssuesStatus(int issueCount, bool completed = false)
        {
            _issueCount = issueCount;
            if (issueCount == 0)
            {
                if (completed)
                {
                    StatusLabel.Image = Resources.tick_circle;
                    StatusLabel.Text = RubberduckUI.CodeInspections_NoIssues;
                }
                else
                {
                    StatusLabel.Image = Resources.hourglass;
                    StatusLabel.Text = RubberduckUI.CodeInspections_Inspecting;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (completed)
                {
                    StatusLabel.Image = Resources.exclamation_diamond;
                    StatusLabel.Text = string.Format("{0} issue" + (issueCount != 1 ? "s" : string.Empty), issueCount);
                }
                else
                {
                    StatusLabel.Image = Resources.hourglass;
                    StatusLabel.Text = string.Format("{0} ({1} issue" + (issueCount != 1 ? "s" : string.Empty) + ")", RubberduckUI.CodeInspections_Inspecting, issueCount);
                }
            }
        }

        private int _issueCount;
        public void EnableRefresh(bool enabled = true)
        {
            RefreshButton.Enabled = enabled;
            QuickFixButton.Enabled = enabled && _issueCount > 0;
        }

        public event EventHandler CopyResults;
        private void CopyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var handler = CopyResults;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }

        private void QuickFixButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            QuickFixItemClick(QuickFixButton.DropDownItems.Cast<ToolStripMenuItem>().First(item => item.Checked), EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        private void PreviousButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var previousIssueIndex = (CodeIssuesGridView.SelectedRows[0].Index == 0)
                ? CodeIssuesGridView.Rows.Count - 1
                : CodeIssuesGridView.SelectedRows[0].Index - 1;

            CodeIssuesGridView.Rows[previousIssueIndex].Selected = true;
            var item = CodeIssuesGridView.Rows[previousIssueIndex].DataBoundItem as CodeInspectionResultGridViewItem;
            OnNavigateCodeIssue(item);
        }

        private void NextButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (CodeIssuesGridView.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            var nextIssueIndex = (CodeIssuesGridView.SelectedRows[0].Index == CodeIssuesGridView.Rows.Count - 1)
                ? 0
                : CodeIssuesGridView.SelectedRows[0].Index + 1;

            CodeIssuesGridView.Rows[nextIssueIndex].Selected = true;
            var item = CodeIssuesGridView.Rows[nextIssueIndex].DataBoundItem as CodeInspectionResultGridViewItem;
            OnNavigateCodeIssue(item);
        }

        private IDictionary<string, Action<VBE>> _availableQuickFixes;
        private void CodeIssuesGridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var enableNavigation = (CodeIssuesGridView.SelectedRows.Count != 0);
            NextButton.Enabled = enableNavigation;
            PreviousButton.Enabled = enableNavigation;
            GoButton.Enabled = enableNavigation;
            CopyButton.Enabled = enableNavigation;

            var quickFixMenu = QuickFixButton.DropDownItems;
            if (quickFixMenu.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var quickFixButton in quickFixMenu.Cast<ToolStripMenuItem>())
                {
                    quickFixButton.Click -= QuickFixItemClick;
                }
            }

            if (CodeIssuesGridView.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
            {
                var issue = (CodeInspectionResultGridViewItem) CodeIssuesGridView.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem;
                _availableQuickFixes = issue.GetInspectionResultItem()
                    .GetQuickFixes();
                var descriptions = _availableQuickFixes.Keys.ToList();

                quickFixMenu.Clear();
                foreach (var caption in descriptions)
                {
                    var item = (ToolStripMenuItem) quickFixMenu.Add(caption);
                    if (quickFixMenu.Count > 0)
                    {
                        item.CheckOnClick = false;
                        item.Checked = quickFixMenu.Count == 1;
                        item.Click += QuickFixItemClick;
                    }
                }
            }

            QuickFixButton.Enabled = QuickFixButton.HasDropDownItems;
        }

        public event EventHandler<QuickFixEventArgs> QuickFix;
        private void QuickFixItemClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var quickFixButton = (ToolStripMenuItem)sender;
            if (QuickFix == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            var args = new QuickFixEventArgs(_availableQuickFixes[quickFixButton.Text]);
            QuickFix(this, args);
        }

        public void SetContent(IEnumerable<CodeInspectionResultGridViewItem> inspectionResults)
        {
            var results = inspectionResults.ToList();

            CodeIssuesGridView.DataSource = new BindingList<CodeInspectionResultGridViewItem>(results);
            CodeIssuesGridView.Refresh();
        }

        private void GoButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var issue = CodeIssuesGridView.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem as CodeInspectionResultGridViewItem;
            OnNavigateCodeIssue(issue);
        }

        public event EventHandler<NavigateCodeEventArgs> NavigateCodeIssue;
        private void CodeIssuesGridView_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.RowIndex < 0)
            {
                return;
            }
            var issue = CodeIssuesGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem as CodeInspectionResultGridViewItem;
            OnNavigateCodeIssue(issue);
        }

        private void OnNavigateCodeIssue(CodeInspectionResultGridViewItem item)
        {
            var handler = NavigateCodeIssue;
            if (handler == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            var result = item.GetInspectionResultItem();
            handler(this, new NavigateCodeEventArgs(result.QualifiedSelection));
        }

        public event EventHandler RefreshCodeInspections;
        private void RefreshButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var handler = RefreshCodeInspections;
            if (handler == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            toolStrip1.Refresh();

            handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

The thing works... but something's definitely off - `RefreshAsync` is running more often than it should.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your event handler naming confused me at first.  The standard naming convention is that `OnEventName` *raises* the event.  And the standard handler looks like `ObjectName_EventName`.

```
public class ClassWithEvent : IDisposable
{
    public event EventHandler SomeEvent;
    protected virtual void OnSomeEvent()
    {
        var e = SomeEvent;
        if (e != null)
            e(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        SomeEvent = null;
    }
}

public class ClassListensToEvent
{
    private ClassWithEvent myClass;

    public ClassListensToEvent()
    {
        myClass.SomeEvent += myClass_SomeEvent;
    }

    private void myClass_SomeEvent(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
    }
}
```

I would do some heavy refactoring to `RefreshAsync` and how it's used.  I don't completely understand your workflow but I would expect that `RefreshAsync` could be cancelled.  No point in refreshing with out of date results.  I would use a `CancellationTokenSource` and pass a `CancellationToken` to both `RefreshAsync` and `Task.Run` like this:

```
Task.Run(() => RefreshAsync(token), token);
```

If you get updated results the first thing you would do is call `CancellationTokenSource.Cancel()` to stop any existing refresh.  Inside `RefreshAsync` you can catch and swallow `TaskCancelledException` gracefully.

Finally, `RefreshAsync` is not very asynchronous.  You're using `Invoke` several times which is blocking on the UI thread.  Ideally `RefreshAsync` would be asynchronous until completion and then update the GUI once at the end (via `BeginInvoke`).

With these changes you can cancel `RefreshAsync` so you're not wasting cycles on old data or painting old results on the GUI.

Comment: @Mat'sMug didn't I already open an issue about being able to cancel a parse?

Comment: You're right, `RefreshAsync` isn't *really* async. It's `async` only so it can `await` the `_inspector` call which is where the real hard and UI-blocking work is happening. The `Invoke` calls merely update the status bar... but yeah they could probably be called from the UI thread anyway. @RubberDuck you did, you did ;-)

Comment: @Mat'sMug If that's the case the `await _inspector` call should allow you to pass a `CancellationToken` as well.  If it's expensive, and potentially operating on old data, it should allow cancellation.

Comment: It definitely will by the time this code hits my `master` branch! thanks! :)

Answer (score 6):

Just a few quick shoots..

To reduce the small code duplication here

> ```
> private void OnParseCompleted(object sender, ParseCompletedEventArgs e)
> {
>     ToggleParsingStatus(false);
>     if (sender == this)
>     {
>         _needsResync = false;
>         _parseResults = e.ParseResults;
>         Task.Run(() => RefreshAsync());
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         _parseResults = e.ParseResults;
>         _needsResync = true;
>     }
> }
> ```

you can refactor this to

```
private void OnParseCompleted(object sender, ParseCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    ToggleParsingStatus(false);
    _parseResults = e.ParseResults;
    _needsResync = sender != this
    if (!needsResync)
    {
        Task.Run(() => RefreshAsync());
    }
}
```

---

Inside the `private async Task RefreshAsync()` method you have some more "problems". First you should reduce the horizontal spacing by using a guard clause on `if (VBE == null)` and return early.

The next problem is here

> ```
>  var parseResults = _parseResults.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Project == VBE.ActiveVBProject);
> ```

can you see it ?? A call to `SingleOrDefault()` will based on the name return either a **single** item or a default item. A single item **!=** plural ! So rename the local variable to `parseResult`.

At a closer look at these two `if` statements

> ```
>     if (_parseResults == null || _needsResync)
>     {
>         _inspector.Parse(VBE, this);
>         return;
>     }
>
>     var parseResults = _parseResults.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Project == VBE.ActiveVBProject);
>     if (parseResults == null || _needsResync)
>     {
>         _inspector.Parse(VBE, this);
>         return;
>     }
> ```

we see that at the second `if` condition we can omit the `|| _needsResync` because this won't ever be `true`.

---

Just seen the nice way how you write tenary expressions.

Comment: Forgot to mention, ..when another feature parses the code, the parser handlers run; not just when this class asks for a reparse! E.g. when code explorer parses, `_needsResync` will be true ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Small comment, I would refactor OnCopyResultsToClipboard like this:

```
    private void OnCopyResultsToClipboard(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var results = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, _results.Select(FormatResultForClipboard));
        var plural = _results.Count != 1 ? "s" : string.Empty;
        var text = string.Format("Rubberduck Code Inspections - {0}{3}{1} issue{2} found.{3} {4}",
                        DateTime.Now, _results.Count, plural, Environment.NewLine, results);

        Clipboard.SetText(text);
    }
```

You were using string concatenations alongside string format which struck me as odd.